# SoftConsole VS Keil for Smatfusion2 or any other development environment?

Tags: arm, cortex-m3, keil, microsemi-fpga, softconsole

In order to program the ARM Cortex-M3 processor which is embedded in the Microsemi FPGA board ***SmartFusion2***, I think there is two possibilities (correct me if wrong):

1. **Keil MDK** (Microcontroller Development Kit) provided by ARM.
2. **SoftConsole** a software development environment provided by Microsemi.

One obvious thing is that *SoftConsole* is free while the other presents a limited free version.

Comment: There is no TrustZone on Cortex-M3

Comment: yes you are right, only **Cortex-M23** and **Cortex-M33** have the TrustZone technology when it comes to the ARMv8. However, still the question, is Keil the only kit that allows the use of this technology ?

Comment: I don't see why Trustzone would require a special IDE. I am working with trustzone using Eclipse with arm compiler.

Comment: I am just not sure because I am totally new in that, I read that the trustZone brings more security to the ARM processor/microcontroller and it is bringing a "breakthrough" with the so called **Platform Security Architecture (PSA)** and while checking which ARM MDK edition supports the ARM Cortex-M23/M33 I found out that it is not free, so I thought it may require special issues in order to be able to deal with it. For example I did not know that I can do it with Eclipse and arm compiler. thx for the hint !

Comment: anything that generates the right machine code will work, your list is only a fraction of the tools available, notably gnu and llvm, plus some number of others which are not all just wrappers around gnu.  Trustzone is just bits in memory/registers so if you can generate the code you can generate the code, dont see how a toolchain matters, and if it did then arm would start with their own tools and also gnu tools and you would have to pay for the libraries.